# Disable all links of User after deactivating in Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to disable all link of users at a time after deactivating users. So, for that I wrote a code like this

```
     def link_to(*user)
       if user_link_disabled?(user.id)
         return nil
       else
         super
       end
     end

     def user_link_disabled?(user_id)
       User.where(activation: false).pluck(:name).include?(user_id)
     end
```

But I am getting this error

```
 undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x007efee4667d00>
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a column to your users model:

deactivated => type boolean

```
user.deactivated? #will return true or false
```

In your view you can then use link_to_unless

```
link_to_unless(user.deactivated, name, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the scope because you didnt display anymore info but it could just be user_id in your if statement or try id[params[:id] instead of user.id but I'm not sure with out more context.

Comment: I have tried this one, it is not showing error now but link disabled is not working.

Answer (score 0):

IN following method

```
def user_link_disabled?(user_id)
  User.where(activation: false).pluck(:name).include?(user_id)
end
```

You are going to pluck `name` from user table records but you are checking `include?` for `user.id`, I think you should pluck `id` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not gonna comment on your preferred code/method for overriding the the `link_to` helper. There is not much context available for that.

But to solve the particular error you are getting:

Your are defining method like this `def link_to(*user)`  .

Here `*user` means it is expecting an `Array` as argument to the method and using the Ruby splat(*), it is converting it to normal arguments.

So if you call this as `link_to [1,2,3]`, it will be same as calling a method with 3 arguments. That is `link_to (1,2,3)` but the argument `user` will be an Array.

So in here `if user_link_disabled?(user.id)`, you are calling a `id` on a `Array` data type. That's why you are getting an error.
Depending on your use, either remove the `*` from method definition,

or

Use looping, if you are going to pass multiple users data to method, like:

```
def link_to(*user)
   user.each do |u|
    if user_link_disabled?(u.id)
      return nil
    else
      super
    end
   end
 end
```

As I mentioned in beginning, I don't know much about the context. So can not comment about the right way but if I may suggest, then I would suggest to use a custom helper for all user routes. like below pseudo code:

```
def link_to_user(user)
  deactivated = user.deactivated?
  if deactivated
    # render some disabled link
  else
    # render link
  end
end
```

Comment: I have used loop as you suggested but now I am getting this error. 
undefined method `id' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x0000000740a978>

Comment: I guess, that's because you are using `link_to` in wrong way. The first argument for it should be the link text(string) and then the url(user) argument but here you have only one so it is taking that argument is as a string passing it through buffer. Try bringing to signature like [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)